# Image as an html button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an image that I want it to act like a button to preform an java-script onclick on it, everything is working fine except when I click over the image it returns to the top of the page, I want it the page to stay on the same place that I am scrolling (middle of the page  for example) when I click over the link image.
This is my code

```
<a id="dell" href="#"><img src="images/logo80.png" width="80" height="80" alt="Dell" /></a>
```

Comment: Add your javascript code

Comment: actully it is jquery  this is it 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#dell").click(function(){
    $("#boarder").toggle(500);
  });
});
</script>
it is for displaying and hiding a block of text under the image

Comment: change it to this and see if it reoccurs `<script> $(document).ready(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); $("#dell").click(function(){ $("#boarder").toggle(500); }); }); </script> `

Comment: no Mr - Wahtever your code is not working at all

Comment: he has the preventDefault() call in the wrong place. Please see my answer.

Comment: yes you are right, i made a mistake with the placement of prevent default as per -joshthecoder- answer `<script> $(document).ready(function(){ $("#dell").click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); $("#boarder").toggle(500); }); }); </script>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to prevent the default action for the a tag or it will use the href.

Try this in your event handler.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dell").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#boarder").toggle(500);
    });
});
```

Another thought is that you actually don't need an a tag if you aren't using it to navigate somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to surround it with an

```
<a>
```

tag, this is what taking you to the top of the document (href="#").

If you want to set the cursor to be a hand icon do it through css:

```
img { cursor: hand; cursor: pointer; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using inline javascript.

```
<a id="dell" href="#" onclick="alert('hello world!'); return false;"><img src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/37332fa8c2654aef804e417e3788e977.png" width="80" height="80" alt="Dell" /></a>
```

Answer (score -3):

Well the problem is just about your  tag. 
You've set an href='#' which means "reloading", that is why the browser brings you up to the page.

In order to set a javascript event on click try the following:

Otherwise there are other methods like the property onclick='nameOfYourFunction()'
or jQuery events.

Comment: it doesn't mean "reloading" it means null value.

Comment: tecnically, it means "go to the anchor with no name", and if it isn't found, go to the top of the page"